# Ajax.beginform executing full postback instead of partial

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In a view I have ajax form like below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowPartial", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId="dane"
}))
{
  // My menu here
}
@Html.Partial("ShowPartial")
```

ShowPartial is connected with this controller method:

```
    public ActionResult ShowPartial(string DeviceName, string submit, int? Page)
    {
        List<Expression<Func<DeviceInstance, bool>>> where = new List<Expression<Func<DeviceInstance, bool>>>();
        int PageNo = 1;
        if (Page.HasValue)
        {
            PageNo = Page.Value;
        }
        if (DeviceName != "" && DeviceName != null)
        {
            where.Add(w => w.Device.Name.Contains(DeviceName));
        }
        return PartialView(unitOfWork.deviceInstanceRepository.Get(where, q => q.OrderBy(o => o.Id), PageNo, w => w.Device, w => w.DeviceUsage));
    }
```

And PartialView:

```
@model IEnumerable<magazyn.Models.DeviceInstance>
<table class="table table-striped" id="dane">
    <tr>
        //table headers
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        // rendering table contet
    }

</table>
```

Can anyone tell me why code above is making full postback instead of partial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this working solution -

Let your main Controller action be as shown below -

```
    public ActionResult Ajax()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And it will return following View. I have installed [Unobstructive Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) nuget and referenced its js script as shown below.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ajax";
}

<h2>Ajax</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowPartial", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "dane"
}))
{
    <input type="submit" value="click"/>
}

<div id="dane">
    @Html.Action("ShowPartial")
</div>
```

Then I have one more controller action which will get hit when this ajax request is made. This controller action would return your partial view -

```
    public ActionResult ShowPartial()
    {
        return PartialView("MyPartial");
    }
```

And the partial view is as follows -

```
<div>
    @DateTime.Now
</div>
```

And when you run the application and click on the button, datetime will be changed in the div without a postback -

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Problem was in Unobtrusive ajax missing as I wrote in my own answer. But I'll accept yours :)

Answer (score 12):

I didn't know that Microsoft's ajax helpers depends on Jquery+ Microsoft jquery plugin.
After realizing that I found needed plugin and downloaded it with package manager.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```