# Form inside MVC Loop submitting automatically in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

For some reason the forms are automatically being submitted in Chrome, but not in Firefox.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
@foreach (var friend in Model.FacebookFriends2.Where(d => !Model.CaseContacts.Select(c => c.ImportedFrom.Replace("Facebook_", "")).Contains(d.ID) && d.FullName.StartsWith(heading.ToString())))
{
    <li class="@string.Format("row{0}", friend.ID)">
        @{
            var fullName = friend.FullName;
            if (fullName.Length > 30)
            {
                fullName = fullName.Substring(0, 30) + "...";
            }
        }
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyConnections", new {@caseid = Model.LayoutViewModel.CurrentCaseID, 
            @img = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + @friend.ID + "/picture?width=720&height=720", 
            @UNQID = friend.ID, @source = "Facebook"}, 
            new AjaxOptions {HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "MyConnections"}))
        {
            <a class="fblinkadd" href="javascript:void" onclick="$('.@string.Format("row{0}", friend.ID)').hide();">
                <span class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/@friend.ID/picture?height=55&width=55">
                </span> @fullName
            </a>
        }
    </li>
}
```

then using this script at the bottom of the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fblinkadd').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post about Ajax.Beginform.  I didn't see anything in your example that shows what you want to replace the HTML with that is tagged with "MyConnections"

[Ajax.beginform executing full postback instead of partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903665/ajax-beginform-executing-full-postback-instead-of-partial)

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ShowPartial", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "dane"
}))
{
    <input type="submit" value="click"/>
}

<div id="dane">
    @Html.Action("ShowPartial")
</div>
```

Comment: It's in a different section of code but on the same page.  It is doing the partial postback correctly though.  Works in Firefox no problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this might help but maybe on the anchor tag change href="javascript:void" to a simple href="#" see if that might be causing odd behavior on the other browsers?